# How to properly configure database schema & inserts

Tags: sql

So I have the following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE user_group (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  group_table_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT user_group_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
  CONSTRAINT user_group_group_table_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (group_table_id) REFERENCES group_table(id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_table
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  group_name VARCHAR(255),
  group_picture_url VARCHAR(255),
  tags VARCHAR(255),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  event_id BIGINT,
  user_group_id BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT group_table_user_group_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_group_id) REFERENCES user_group(id)
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  display_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  picture_url VARCHAR(255),
  user_group_id BIGINT,
  event_response_id BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT user_user_group_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_group_id) REFERENCES user_group(id),
);
```

How can I make it so that this is a valid statement? In the sense that I should be able to create a user_group table, group_table table, or user table without needing the others.

The other question that I have is. Say this statement is valid and the tables exist. How would I insert data into user_group?

```
INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'role')
```

Would require that both a group_table and a user with id's of 2 and 3 respectively already exist upon insert of the value.

Comment: It's impossible to get mentioned error when inserting into `announcement` (without triggers). Please post your complete schema.

Comment: The error seems to be more along the lines of the database is requiring that a group_table with id of 12 be created before I can insert into announcement. How can I make it so that the group_table id is not required to exist upon insert of an announcement?

Comment: Take a careful look at error message: `GROUP_TABLE_EVENT_ID_FK` is violated. That means error occurs during `group_table` manipulation, not  `announcement` one. Again: show us more (schema and your script).

Comment: Hmm I guess I made an error in what I meant to post then. All I want to work is for an announcement to be allowed to be inserted even if the group_table_id does not exist for the announcement. For the purpose of this question you can ignore the constraints on group and treat the error as announcement_group_table_id_fk being violated.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly please.

Comment: Any specific reason why you removed the `h2` tag? So which database are you using then?

Comment: it's a really bad idea to name a table `user` . It won't be portable

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it so that this is a valid statement? In the sense that I should be able to create a user_group table, group_table table, or user table without needing the others.

You can create the tables first, and create the foreign key constraints after. If you try to do both at the same time (like you currently have), you run into a chicken and egg situation.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
CREATE TABLE user_group (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  group_table_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE group_table
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  group_name VARCHAR(255),
  group_picture_url VARCHAR(255),
  tags VARCHAR(255),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  event_id BIGINT,
  user_group_id BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  display_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  picture_url VARCHAR(255),
  user_group_id BIGINT,
  event_response_id BIGINT
);

alter table user_group
add constraint user_group_user_id_fk
foreign key (user_id) 
references user(id);

alter table user_group
add constraint user_group_group_table_id_fk
foreign key (group_table_id)
REFERENCES group_table(id);

alter table group_table
add constraint group_table_user_group_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (user_group_id)
REFERENCES user_group(id);

alter table user
add constraint user_user_group_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (user_group_id)
REFERENCES user_group(id);
```

> The other question that I have is. Say this statement is valid and the tables exist. How would I insert data into user_group?
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'role')
> ```
>
> Would require that both a group_table and a user with id's of 2 and 3 respectively already exist upon insert of the value.

Yes, the corresponding rows in `user` (`id = 2`) and `group` (`id = 3`) would have to be inserted prior to attempting the insert into `user_group`.